# Laravel Socialite - Difference between SocialiteProvider Microsoft Graph and Microsoft Azure

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, laravel-socialite

I want to make an app for my organisation using SSO via Office365. I found the Socialite plugin for Laravel and now I am wondering: What is the difference between Microsoft Graph and Microsoft Azure Provider?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some usefull informations:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

TLDR: Use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure, because the Azure Version will be deprecated.